# Clang error in Unity Integrated Native application

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I tried lot of libraries to build unity in native app. Most of them are outdated. Here I tried tutorial in youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7YxPf6a32g) but having clang error. Couldn't fix..

```
Ld /Users/riverswave4apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityNative-dtzfqcybbuktpadpmmqrlhoorkgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UnityNative.app/UnityNative normal arm64 (in target: UnityNative)
    cd /Users/riverswave4apple/Desktop/UnityNative
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.1
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -L/Users/riverswave4apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityNative-dtzfqcybbuktpadpmmqrlhoorkgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/riverswave4apple/Desktop/UnityNative/../CubeTestBuild -L/Users/riverswave4apple/Desktop/UnityNative/../CubeTestBuild/Libraries -F/Users/riverswave4apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityNative-dtzfqcybbuktpadpmmqrlhoorkgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/riverswave4apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityNative-dtzfqcybbuktpadpmmqrlhoorkgi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/UnityNative.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityNative.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityNative.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/riverswave4apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityNative-dtzfqcybbuktpadpmmqrlhoorkgi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/UnityNative.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityNative.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityNative_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -weak_framework iAd -liconv.2 -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework MediaPlayer -framework Foundation -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreText -weak-liPhone-lib -lil2cpp -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/riverswave4apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityNative-dtzfqcybbuktpadpmmqrlhoorkgi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/UnityNative.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityNative.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityNative_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/riverswave4apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityNative-dtzfqcybbuktpadpmmqrlhoorkgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UnityNative.app/UnityNative

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio", referenced from:
      AVFoundationVideoPlayback::PlayerPriv::ProcessAudioTap(opaqueMTAudioProcessingTap const*, long, unsigned int, AudioBufferList*, long*, unsigned int*) in libiPhone-lib.a(AVFoundationVideoPlayback.o)
  "_MTAudioProcessingTapCreate", referenced from:
      -[AVFoundationMediaLoader ConfigureAudioOutput] in libiPhone-lib.a(AVFoundationVideoPlayback.o)
  "_MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage", referenced from:
      -[AVFoundationMediaLoader ConfigureAudioOutput] in libiPhone-lib.a(AVFoundationVideoPlayback.o)
      AVFoundationVideoPlayback::PlayerPriv::PrepareAudioTap(opaqueMTAudioProcessingTap const*, long, AudioStreamBasicDescription const*) in libiPhone-lib.a(AVFoundationVideoPlayback.o)
      AVFoundationVideoPlayback::PlayerPriv::ProcessAudioTap(opaqueMTAudioProcessingTap const*, long, unsigned int, AudioBufferList*, long*, unsigned int*) in libiPhone-lib.a(AVFoundationVideoPlayback.o)
      AVFoundationVideoPlayback::PlayerPriv::FinalizeAudioTap(opaqueMTAudioProcessingTap const*) in libiPhone-lib.a(AVFoundationVideoPlayback.o)
      -[AVFoundationMediaLoader StopOutput] in libiPhone-lib.a(AVFoundationVideoPlayback.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Could be that your plugin is meant only for arm7. You could try to set it to only build that architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linked Frameworks and Libraries, make the status of AVFoundation.framework as optional. Add Metal (optional), Security(req.) and MediaToolbox(req.) frameworks to it.

In Build Settings,

```
-Double check all header files and Prefix header path are correct.


-ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND = NO

- Other Linker Flags add this line. -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup

- Mismatched Return type = YES

- CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS- YES
```

Stop the application clean build it.